# I'd like to disable one IBAction Button and enable another

Tags: ios, button

What I would like to do is disable one button when clicked, and enable another.

This is my current code

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {      
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    var view = UIView()
    view = sender as! UIView
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false

}


@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    var view = UIView()
    view = sender as! UIView
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false

}
```

So when a button is clicked, it's disabled (but not greyed out) out and that's fine, it's what I want. But I would like it so when a user clicks the alternate button, the previous button is enabled again.

Comment: I presume that these buttons are in a tableview cell?  I would create a custom table view cell class so that you have easy reference to the two buttons.  Also set a property for the index path and use delegation to pass events back to the view controller so that it can perform the update/save operations

Comment: Yeah, I figured this might be what I would have to, but I was seeing if there were other methods, as I didn't want to go about it that way since I can't shake an error when I try it that way. @Paulw11

Comment: It is the best way to do it, in my opinion.  The biggest risk is not handing cell reuse properly.